# React-Native DrawerNavigator Menu on both sides

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have a react native app with a DrawerNavigator. For the menu I have my own component. That works great.
Now I want to add a second side menu on the right side. 
Is it possible to have two DrawerNavigator like in the Slack App?
This solution is not working for me: https://snack.expo.io/ry7lYempe
because I don't want to have a TabController as parent. Both Drawer should be accessible in all screens.

My code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import reducer from './src/reducers'
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import SidebarMenu from './src/components/layout/SidebarMenu'

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

let store = createStore(reducer);

import News from './src/screens/News'
import HowTo from './src/screens/HowTo'


export default class MyApp extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <MainNavigator />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

const MainNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
    {
        News: {
            path: '/news',
            screen: News
        },
        HowTo: {
            path: '/howto',
            screen: HowTo
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'News',
        drawerPosition: 'left',
        contentComponent: SidebarMenu
    }
);
```

Solved after updating react-navigation to the newest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add any drawer you want, take a look at this exemple https://snack.expo.io/BJoChzewM

In your case, you may add your "MainNavigator" in another DrawerNavigator Component. don't forget to set drawerOpenRoute/drawerCloseRoute to prevent any side effects.

Comment: Thanks, no I have two Drawers. But when I open the right one, the left one opens too. I have added the routes: 
`const MainDrawerExample = DrawerNavigator({
    Drafts: {
        screen: DrawerExample,
    },
}, {
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    contentComponent: BookmarkMenu,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerRightOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerRightClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerRightToggle'
});`

Comment: please, share your code using https://snack.expo.io, I will take a look

Comment: I finally found the problem: I was working with an old version of react-navigation. After I updated the module it worked... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @emma93 can you please share your solution I am trying to do the same

Answer (score 1):

@KamleshKatpara Here is my solution (I nested the two navigators):

```
const DrawerExample = DrawerNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            path: '/',
            screen: Home
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
        drawerPosition: 'left',
        contentComponent: SidebarMenu
    }
);

const MainDrawerExample = DrawerNavigator({
    Drafts: {
        screen: DrawerExample,
    }
}, {
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    contentComponent: BookmarkMenu,
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerRightOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerRightClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerRightToggle'
});
```