# How to show a NavigationDrawer in both sides of Screen in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my React-native project, I have made one Custom drawer navigation which appears from the left side of the screen.

Here's my code for that class which include the set up for the navigation screens-

**HomeScreen.js**

```
class NavigationDrawerStructure extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null ,
  };

  toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
  };
  render() {
    return (

      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
          {/*Donute Button Image */}
         <Icon name='menu'/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  First: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),


  },

  ScreenInternal: {
    screen: BookDetails,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Screen With Navigation Drawer',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },


});

const Screen2_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Second: {
    screen: CategoryBrowse,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Create Note',
      headerLeft: <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF9800',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});



const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({

  Screen1: {
    screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',

      drawerIcon: (
        <Icon name='home' size={25}

        />
      )

    },
  },

  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Category',
      drawerIcon: (
        <Image  source={require('../assets/splash.png')}  
        style={{height:25, width:25,}}

        />
      )
    },
  },

},

{
  contentComponent: CustomSidebarMenu,
  drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width - 130,
},

);


const Drawer2 = createDrawerNavigator({
  Screen1: {
    screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Home',

      drawerIcon: (
        <Icon name='home' size={25}

        />
      )

    },
  },

  Screen2: {
    screen: Screen2_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Category',
      drawerIcon: (
        <Image  source={require('../assets/splash.png')}  
        style={{height:25, width:25,}}

        />
      )
    },
  },


},


{

  drawerType: 'back',
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    drawerWidth: 200,
    drawerBackgroundColor: 'orange',
  //For the Custom sidebar menu we have to provide our CustomSidebarMenu
  contentComponent: CustomSidebarMenu,
  //Sidebar width
  drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width - 130,
},

);


const DrawerNavigatorExample = createStackNavigator({
  Drawer: { screen: Drawer, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
  ScreenExternal: {
    screen: ScreenExternal,
    navigationOptions: { title: 'Details Note' },
  },

},
);


export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigatorExample);
```

In my code I have declared a const Drawer which is the screen I have added in DrawerNavigatorExample and exported that at last.

I have made another const Drawer2 which contains the screens that will appear from right side.

Now, the problem is:

I don't know how to use this **Drawer2(Right side one)** along with **Drawer(Left side one)** as in the declaration of **DrawerNavigatorExample** I can set only one value in Drawer screen.

I also checked the following solution:

[React-Native DrawerNavigator Menu on both sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754768/react-native-drawernavigator-menu-on-both-sides)

but that didn't help.

So, How can I show both the right and left drawer at the same screen?